# Hosting SQL Server 2005 to website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2005

I may seem silly asking this question. But since I am still a learner, I'm posting this question.

I have launched my asp.net website but I a unable to understand as to how to host the database i.e., SQL Server 2005. I have added the mdf file to the remote website, changed the connection string in the web.config to localhost as  the data source.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install Sql Server on the remote server that is running your website. Is that done already?

You can download Sql Server 2008 Express to get started with and install it on the remote server.

Where are you hosting your website? Is in your own server?

If it's a 3rd party hosting site, they may already have sql server running. You can check with them.

(You should probably provide more details about where and how you're hosting your app to get better feed back.)

Comment: Thanks. Its a third party provider.